# What is the difference between release and iteration?

Tags: release, iteration

The title says What is the difference between release and iteration? Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: I haven't seen standard definitions of those words. I see a sprint/iteration as a period of time that produces something. It may or may not be released outside the organization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterations are basically single units of work within your release plan.  Typically, your [iteration planning phase](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/iterationplanning.html) will be a short (1-4 week) series of tasks that will be done.

After an iteration, there should be a series of [acceptance tests](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/functionaltests.html).  This verifies that the problem domain was handled correctly.

The series of iterations plus acceptance lead to a single [release](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/commit.html).  The release leads to deployment, whether to a customer or internal usage *by the end user* (which is the critical difference).

Granted, in many teams, the lines can blur a bit, especially if you're releasing every iteration, etc...

Answer (score 4):

An iteration can be purely internal. A release goes out to a customer.

Answer (score -2):

We can say in simple words, Release is "What to do" and Iteration is "How to do".
Release focuses on User stories and iterations focuses on Tasks decomposed from user stories.