# What is the difference between release and iteration on JIRA?

Tags: iteration, release, jira

What is the difference between release and iteration on JIRA?
:)

Answer (score 1):

As Jira is a tool that manage Agile teams, they use the same language, 
[just have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800083/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-iteration) to understand the meaning of iteration and release in an Agile context.