# What's the difference between version and Iteration on jira?

Tags: version, iteration, jira

What is the difference between version and Iteration on JIRA?

Why the display is the same between version and iteration on JIRA.
Except Points targeted, Points completed, Points Accumulated.

It should be

Version 
==Release

- Sprint1
- Sprint2

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787211/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-iteration-on-jira

Answer (score 1):

Think of drafts of a document as iterations, which finally converges to the final draft called "1".   A year later the document is updated, revised, etc. and called "2".  "2" , also having gone through numerous drafts, i.e., iterations, would be the latest version of "1".

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, a version is a specific instance of a file and an iteration is a period of time. It may be that your site chooses to assign version numbers that coincide with iteration numbers but that would be a distinction made by your own company policies.